# how to compare numbers from array elements then get common numbers from start php

Tags: php, arrays

**Problem 1:**
array(670006151,670006152,670006251)
output: 670006151,152,251

**Problem 2:**
array(670006151,670006154,670006158)
output: 670006151,4,8

**Problem 3:**
array(670006151,670006154,670006161)
output: 670006151,54,61

anyone know how to get output from different arrays, I need to find a common number from start then append other elements in the above problems 670006 is common in all this can be any number...

Comment: Could you write your tried, reproducible php code in your question?

Comment: So, longest common prefix among strings?

Comment: What is the desired output for `array(670006151,670006151,670006151)` ?

Comment: Thanks, @nice_dev.

Comment: Thank you, @nick both solutions are working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to divide each of the numbers by increasing powers of 10, stopping when the result is the same for each of them. Then subtract that result multiplied by the power from the 2nd to last entries in the array:

```
function common_parts($data) {
    for ($b = 1; ; $b *= 10) {
        $base = intdiv($data[0], $b);
        $matches = array_filter($data, function ($v) use ($b, $base) { return intdiv($v, $b) != $base; });
        if (count($matches) == 0) break;
    }
    $base *= $b;
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $data[$i] = $data[$i] - $base;
    }
    return $data;
}

print_r(common_parts(array(670006151,670006152,670006251)));
print_r(common_parts(array(670006151,670006154,670006158)));
print_r(common_parts(array(670006151,670006154,670006161)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 670006151
    [1] => 152
    [2] => 251
)
Array
(
    [0] => 670006151
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 8
)
Array
(
    [0] => 670006151
    [1] => 54
    [2] => 61
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4avn9)

Comment: WOW ... not going to post my solution

Comment: You should - it's always good to see multiple ways of solving a problem

Answer (score 0):

- Loop over all elements of the array.
- Convert each number to a string.
- Compare the current longest prefix you have with the current number at hand.
- Break immediately and update longest common prefix once you find a mismatch.
- Loop over the dataset again and remove the longest prefix you calculated and add the residue of the current number in iteration to result.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

    function getPrefixedData($arr){
        if(count($arr) == 0) return [];
        $longest_prefix = strval($arr[0]);
        foreach($arr as $val){
            $val = strval($val);
            $len = strlen($longest_prefix);
            for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i){
                if($longest_prefix[$i] != $val[$i]){
                    $longest_prefix = substr($longest_prefix,0,$i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        $res = [];
        $len = strlen($longest_prefix);
        foreach($arr as $index => $val){
            if($index == 0) $res[] = $longest_prefix . substr(strval($val),$len);
            else $res[] = substr(strval($val),$len);
        }
        
        return $res;
    }
```

[Fiddle here](https://3v4l.org/UHTf7)